# Input Field with text already populated on page load

Tags: html, salesforce, visualforce, input-field

I have a custom Visual Force page that on load has a name field that is supposed to have {Auto} printed inside the input text box that the user can delete or leave or not.  I have been using a html-placeholder however the text just disappears and is gray.

My VF inputfield:

```
<apex:inputfield required="true"
                value="{!EventPackageRevenueBreakdown__c.Name}"  html-placeholder="{!Auto}"></apex:inputfield>
```

What it looks like with that code: 
[image]

What I need it to look like (notice the cursor is after the closing scope)

[image]

Thanks in advance I'm still very new to this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to set Name field in controller with '{Auto}' value.

Comment: That was it I had to assign the value into the controller! Thanks!

Comment: @NicolePhillips, glad I could help :-)

Answer (score 0):

The placeholder attribute will disappear when there is a value in the field, what you want is to actually set the VALUE of the field to {Auto}.

Try this:

If you want it to automatically clear the field if a user clicks into it, you could add some javascript to handle that.